# How to improve performance of a sybase select query in a single table with self join and without using subquery?

Tags: sybase

Something like.,

```
select * from tab_260 a 
where a.id in (1,2,3,4,5)
and a.date < '151128'
and exists 
(select b.num 
from tab_260 b 
where b.id in (20,30,50)
and b.date < '151128' 
and b.num = a.num )
```

Querying the same table by joining the 'num' field. But it take huge time to execute as there are some 100 million records in the table. Is there any better way to optimize the query to increase the performance much better!!??

Comment: Please show the indexes for the tab_260-table?

Comment: INDEX_NAME
tab_260_ind0    
tab_260_ind_8   
tab_260_ind1    
tab_260_tmp_6   
tab_260_ind_4   
tab_260_ind_5   
tab_260_ind_6   
tab_260_ind_7   
tab_260_ind_2   
tab_260_ind_9   
                      
INDEX_KEYS
jc_num,eq_id - cluseted, unique
num,seg2_code
jc_num,account
s2_code,posted
posted_flag
de_date
ptype
s2_code
acc_code,applied
flag -- please copy to notepad

Comment: You should format the indexes properly so that their columns can be read.  Also, how many rows in each?

Comment: Cannot read the index definitions. Why not just paste the index creation statements? How many rows does the subquery match? How many different ID's are there? How may rows are there for date < '151128' ?